# Barnsley fern in python language

Tags: python-2.7

I need help with this Barnsley fern program. I am not getting the leaf picture at all and getting an error run time message when I run my code I know I am close but need some help

```
#! /usr/bin/env python


import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random

# starting values
x = 0.5
y = 0.0

for i in range(10000):
        rand = (random.randrange(0,1))
        if (rand < 0.02):
                x = 0.5
                y = 0.27*y
        if  ((0.02 <= rand) and (rand <= 0.17)):
                x = -0.139*x + 0.263*y + 0.57
                y = 0.246*x + 0.224*y - 0.036
        if  ((0.17 < rand) and (rand <= 0.3)):
                x = 0.17*x - 0.215*y + 0.408
                y = 0.222*x + 0.176*y + 0.0893
        if ((0.3 < rand) and (rand < 1.0)):
                x = 0.781*x + 0.034*y + 0.1075
                y = -0.032*x +0.739*y + 0.27


plt.plot(x,y,'.')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2):

There are two major issues with your code:

1. `random.randrange(0, 1)` always yields `0`. Try using `random.random()` instead.
2. You need to indent the `plot` command in order to have it executed in every iteration.

Furthermore, it might be better to first collect all coordinates in one large array and then call the plot command. This would probably be more time efficient because you'd call the rendering engine only once.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You only have one point because you only give one `x` and one `y` to `plot`. You need to put your values in a list :

```
# starting values
x = 0.5
y = 0.0
# Lists of coordinates to plot
xlist = [x]
ylist = [y]
for i in range(10000):
        rand = (random.randrange(0,1))
        if (rand < 0.02):
                x = 0.5
                y = 0.27*y
        if  ((0.02 <= rand) and (rand <= 0.17)):
                x = -0.139*x + 0.263*y + 0.57
                y = 0.246*x + 0.224*y - 0.036
        if  ((0.17 < rand) and (rand <= 0.3)):
                x = 0.17*x - 0.215*y + 0.408
                y = 0.222*x + 0.176*y + 0.0893
        if ((0.3 < rand) and (rand < 1.0)):
                x = 0.781*x + 0.034*y + 0.1075
                y = -0.032*x +0.739*y + 0.27
        xvec.append(x)
        yvec.append(y)
plt.plot(x, y, '.')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

use random.uniform(0,1) instead of random.randrange(0,1). It will return a float random between 0 and 1

```
import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
# starting values
x = 0.5
y = 0.0
# Lists of coordinates to plot
xvec = [x]
yvec = [y]
for i in range(10000):
        rand = random.uniform(0, 1)
        if (rand < 0.02):
                x = 0.5
                y = 0.27*y
        if  ((0.02 <= rand) and (rand <= 0.17)):
                x = -0.139*x + 0.263*y + 0.57
                y = 0.246*x + 0.224*y - 0.036
        if  ((0.17 < rand) and (rand <= 0.3)):
                x = 0.17*x - 0.215*y + 0.408
                y = 0.222*x + 0.176*y + 0.0893
        if ((0.3 < rand) and (rand < 1.0)):
                x = 0.781*x + 0.034*y + 0.1075
                y = -0.032*x +0.739*y + 0.27
        xvec.append(x)
        yvec.append(y)
plt.plot(xvec, yvec, '.')
plt.show()
```